# Python Generate a String from Column Names

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am attempting to grab the column names from an incoming parquet file.  I would like to generate a string that will be used later in a spark query.  That string looks like this:

Expected String
'RecordAction|UniqueId|Type|TypeDescription'

```
ColumnNames =['RecordAction', 'UniqueId', 'Type']
    CountofColumns =range(3)

    for columns in ColumnNames[0]:
        print(ColumnNames[0]+'|'+ColumnNames[1]+'|'+ColumnNames[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the coolest features of python is the `join` method in strings. What you want is:

```py
ColumnNames =['RecordAction', 'UniqueId', 'Type']
print('|'.join(ColumnNames))
```